# What is the change in entropy of this system if the partition is removed?

Tags: entropy, ideal-gas

You have 2 matching volumes of the same ideal gas separated by a partition. The gas in both volumes is subject to standard temperature and pressure.

What is the change in entropy of this system if the partition is then removed?

Comment: I think the answer is Nkln(4)  or nRln(4)  or is this a test of conceptual understanding and the answer just zero?

Comment: Steve my answer was wrong and confusing, I am sorry. For 2 of the same ideal gases, entropy does not change but the entropy of mixing  of two different gases is  $ 2Nk Ln2$. I misread your question but I will upvote and give a better chance of confirming this

Comment: Entropy is an extensive quantity, just like the energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entropy change is zero.Entropy is a measure of "**how much we don't know about the system**" ,the **more ignorant** we are about the system the **more the entropy**.

If gases on both sides of the partition were different (gas A and gas B) entropy would have increased after removing the partition. Why?

Because before removing the partition we knew **certainly** gas A is on the left (say) and gas B is on the right of the partition, but after removing the partition we don't know anymore.

Molecules of gas A can be anywhere, on the left side or the right or on both sides. Similar is the case with gas B also.
So uncertainty (ignorance) in position will increase and so thus entropy.

But in our case on both sides, the gases are the same.Some  of the molecules on the left will move to the right and some of the molecules on the right will move to the left,but that does not increase or decrease our ignorance, because you don't know which molecule is from which side, because they are all identical and the gas looks all the same even after the mixing.

So entropy change will be zero.